# How do I freely move a textblock around in a Border in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I cannot seem to freely move a textblock around wherever I want inside a border control. It always snaps to the center. How can I stop this from happening?

This is my markup:

```
<Border BorderThickness="0" Height="258" Margin="30,206,20,188" Name="border2"  Width="406" >
            <Border.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/TestApp;component/Images/blurb.png"/>
            </Border.Background>                
            <TextBlock Height="103" x:Name="tBlk_Steps" Text="{Binding Count}" Width="298" FontSize="56" Foreground="#FF00BCE4" ></TextBlock>
        </Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment properties on the Textblock. You can also control it with the Margin on the TextBlock.

/Anders

Answer (score 0):

Try VerticalAlignment="Top" and HorizontalAlignment="Left"

Alternatively try setting Margin properties on the TextBlock.

One great way to work this sort of thing out is to open up a project in ExpressionBlend - it's Visual designer drives me crazy, but it does also help with some things!